# There are few android installation with no deviceToken on parse.com

Tags: android, parse-platform, google-cloud-messaging, sender-id, android-devicetoken

I have created the project for parse cloud code.

I have developed mobile applications for iOS as well as android.

For iOS everything works fine, but for android it is having an issue with installation.

There are few entries with (undefined) deviceToken and GCMSenderId.

I can see the same issue on [github/ParsePlatform/issues](https://github.com/ParsePlatform/Parse-SDK-Android/issues/90), but did not get the root cause and the solution.

Can anyone please help me to find out the root cause and the solution for that?

Comment: so part of the installations are with device token and part are without?

Comment: Yes, only for some of android devices its not working. DeviceToken and GCMSenderID are blank in installation table which I insert during user registration.

Comment: You are testing it on a simulator or on a real device? maybe it is related to google play services.

Comment: It is working for simulator,  also working for so many android devices, but not working for some devices.

Comment: there is something common to all the devices that have empty device token ?

Answer (score 0):

Google Play Service needs to be installed on user's devices and a google account have to be logged-in in order to use GCM or to get a deviceToken.
That's the Android world we live in. You need to deal with it. Good luck. :)